# How can i completely obliterate the content and properties of a excel cell in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

Is there any simple way to, given a range of cells fetched from a Excel Worksheet (using C#),
delete all its content ?

By all its content i mean : Background turned to white, text = empty, delete formulas and any text format that was previously inserted in that cell / range of cells ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That title sounds pretty violent.

Comment: @DavidLively No, how should i use it to solve my problem ?

Comment: It's a reference to [this XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/451/).

Comment: So, like clear contents and clear formats ?

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problems, basically, manually setting the properties back the their "default" values

```
            cell.Formula = "";
            cell.Value2 = (string) String.Empty;
            cell.Font.Bold = false;
            cell.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
            cell.Font.Size = 10;
            cell.BorderAround();
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
            cell.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(255,255,255));
            cell.ShrinkToFit = false;
```

Thanks anyways :)